# Ignore specific error for eslint in the whole project

Tags: node.js, eslint, adonis.js

I'm using AdonisJs (NodeJS framework) and they created a function called `use` to import file like they'd be namespaces, for example `use('App/Services/User')` instead of `require('../app/Services/User')`.

The problem is that eslint will throw the error `'use' is not defined  no-undef`.

At this time I have two ways:

1. Putting an eslint comment to disable alert for that line in each file, but it's annoying
2. Use `require` instead of `use`, but it's a lot useful the function.

Is there a way to disable "one time for all" the specific `no-undef` for the `use` function in the whole project?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at [globals](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-globals) sections at `.eslintrc` config.

```
{
    "globals": {
        "use": false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can configure you `eslint` on your `.eslintrc.json`
Reference on their official page: https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring

For `no-undef` rule, you can add global in the configuration by

```
{
    "globals": {
        "var1": true,
        "var2": false
    }
}
```

Also specified in their documentation: https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#specifying-globals